# Why can't I establish a tcp connection, via sockets in python, with a root name server?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, tcp, dns

*Background: I want to establish a TCP connection with a root name server so I can send a dns query and inspect the response*

I tried establishing a TCP connection with a root name server using the `socket` module in python, particularly with a.root-servers.net

I wrote the code below in an interactive python shell, in Windows 11.

I ran:

```
import socket
a = socket.socket()
a.connect(("a.root-servers.net", 53))
```

But I get the error:

`TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Why is this the case?

Comment: Did you try a  dig query with `+tcp` to force TCP from the same source? Does it work? There is probably nothing wrong with your code, but more with your network/firewall. Do remember though that DNS works over UDP and TCP.

Answer (score 1):

I get good virtual circuit (TCP) results from this:

```bash
$  time dig +vc +norec ns . @a.root-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> +vc +norec ns . @a.root-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60546
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 27
...
;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 18 14:38:22 PST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 828


real    0m0.056s
```

The end-to-end path from your client
to the root server is different from mine.
Unlike mine, it has one or more filtering
routers (firewalls) that discard port 53
TCP packets.

Doing so violates section 6.1.3.2
of [rfc 1123 host requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-72).
It is essential to allow TCP domain
requests through, as some DNS answers
will not fit within limited size
UDP datagrams.

---

Recommend you ask your local firewall
admin to fix its config, or seek an
alternate internet connectivity solution.